# SQL server sum of multiple counts from subquery

Tags: sql-server, count, sum, subquery

I am trying to get the individual sum of multiple counts as a single row in SQl Server. Below is an example of my query that doesn't work

```
SELECT 
    SUM(A), SUM(B), SUM(C)
FROM
(
    SELECT
       COUNT(CASE T.ID WHEN 1 THEN T.ID END, '', 0) AS [A]
       COUNT(CASE T.ID WHEN 2 THEN T.ID END, '', 0) AS [B]
       COUNT(CASE T.ID WHEN 3 THEN T.ID END, '', 0) AS [C]
    FROM
        MyTable AS T
        INNER JOIN MyOtherTable AS MOT ON T.IDNum = MOT.IDNum
    WHERE
        YEAR(T.MyDate) = 2015
)
```

This throws invalid syntax because I need to alias the subquery. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Please provide schema and data for your two tables so we can look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add an alias to the sub query. It should look like this.

```sql
SELECT 
    SUM(alias_query_name.A), SUM(alias_query_name.B), SUM(alias_query_name.C)
FROM
(SELECT
   COUNT(CASE T.ID WHEN 1 THEN T.ID END, '', 0) AS [A]
   COUNT(CASE T.ID WHEN 2 THEN T.ID END, '', 0) AS [B]
   COUNT(CASE T.ID WHEN 3 THEN T.ID END, '', 0) AS [C]
FROM
    MyTable AS T
    INNER JOIN MyOtherTable AS MOT ON T.IDNum = MOT.IDNum
WHERE
    YEAR(T.MyDate) = 2015
) as alias_query_name -- <----- name of sub query
```